# Error with Aliens in space invaders clone

Tags: java, arrays, game-development

I am writing a space invaders clone for a school project, I am in the process of writing the aliens and their algorithm for movement with the use of an array.
My issue is a bunch of errors occur when I run the code but I can`t find why?

any help would be appreciated and bare in mind I am very inexperienced with game development and java

bellow is my GamePanel class, and then my Alien class

```
package Main;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;

import javax.swing.JPanel;

import entity.Alien;
import entity.Controller;
import entity.Player;
import entity.playerBullet;

public class GamePanel extends JPanel implements Runnable{

    public final int screenHeight = 600;
    public final int screenWidth = 800;
    public final int playerSize = 48;
    int fps = 60;
    KeyHandler keyH = new KeyHandler();
    Thread gameThread;
    public Player player = new Player(this,keyH);
    public CollisionChecker cChecker = new CollisionChecker(this);
    private Controller c = new Controller(null);
    Alien alien;

    
//player default position
     int playerX = 100;
     int playerY = 100;
     int playerSpeed = 4;

        
    
    public GamePanel() {
        this.setPreferredSize(new Dimension (screenWidth, screenHeight)); 
        this.setBackground(Color.black);
        this.setDoubleBuffered(true);
        this.addKeyListener(keyH);
        this.setFocusable(true);

            }
        
    

        
        public void startGameThread() {
            gameThread = new Thread (this);
            gameThread.start();
            alien.initAlien();
    }
    public void run() {
        double drawInterval = 1000000000/fps; // 0.01666 seconds = 60 times per seconds
        double nextDrawTime = System.nanoTime() + drawInterval;
        while(gameThread != null) {
            System.out.println("this game is runing");
            // update information such as character positions
            // draw the screen with the updated information
            update();
            repaint();
            try {
                double remainingTime = nextDrawTime - System.nanoTime();
                remainingTime = remainingTime/1000000;
                if(remainingTime<0) {
                    remainingTime = 0;
                }
                Thread.sleep ((long) remainingTime);
                
                nextDrawTime += drawInterval;
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            
        }
        
    }
    private void update() {
        player.update();
        c.tick();
        alien.moveAliens();
    
        }
    

    
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        // to draw something
        super.paintComponent(g); 
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D)g;
        player.draw(g2);
        c.render(g );
        g2.dispose(); 
        alien.render(g );

        
    }
}
```

Alien class

```
package entity;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;

public class Alien {
boolean isVisible;
boolean moveLeft;
boolean moveRight;
Alien[] a = new Alien[10];
private int x;
private int y;
int ax = 10;
int ay = 10;
public Alien(int x, int y) {

}

public void initAlien() {
    for(int i=0;i<a.length; i++) {
        a[i] = new Alien(ax,ay);
        ax += 40;
        if(i==4) {
            ax=10;
            ay+=40;
        }
    }
}
public void moveAliens() {
    for(int i=0;i<a.length; i++) {
    if (a[i].moveLeft ==true) {
        a[i].x -=2;
    }
    if (a[i].moveRight ==true) {
        a[i].x+=2;
    }
    
    
    for(int i1 = 0; i<a.length; ) {
        if(a[i].x>600) {
            for(int j =0;j<a.length; j++) {
                a[j].moveLeft = true;
                a[j].moveRight = false;
                a[j].y += 5;
            }
        }
    if(a[i].x<0) {
        for(int j = 0; j< a.length; j++) {
            a[j].moveLeft = false;
            a[j].moveRight = true;
            a[j].y += 5;
        }
    }
        
    }

    }



}
```

Comment: Could you include the error message, please? Also less important but it'd be easier to help as well if you formatted your code. Most IDEs will have a command you can run to do basic formatting for you

Comment: Right now the all that happens is one rectangle appears at the top left of the screen.

Comment: Have you tried using a debugger? Most IDEs will come with a debugging tool that lets you stop program at certain lines of code and step through them line by line. It's really useful for finding errors like this